# How to set output as azure blob in FFMPEG command

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob

In my Queue trigger Azure Function, I am resizing video using FFMPEG command.

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg",  "-i", 
                           "input.mp4",
                            "-filter_complex", "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=25",
                            "-c:v","libx264",
                            "-c:a","aac",
                            "-preset:v", "ultrafast",
                            "output.mp4"],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Currently output will be write locally and use azure function local space. What I want that output file directly write to azure container as a blob. And not save it to locally as function has less space and for resizing its required more space which causing issue.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG supports in-memory PIPEs for both the input and output. The in-memory data can be easily stored as a blob in the Blob storage

Comment: how is the question?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here

Comment: the question is how? not what it can do, you answer is not providing how we can achieve that.